# Where is the world's largest commercial elevator?

Tags: where-on-earth, architecture

Out of curiosity, I went to search for "world's largest elevator", but all the results were for grain elevators.

Now obviously, you can't ride in a grain elevator. What I meant was, what is the largest commercial elevator that humans can use? Large as in terms of square feet. I couldn't find anything of the sort.

Comment: I got several relevant results searching for "largest passenger elevator", which might help narrow down your search.

Answer (score 13):

If you don't mind floating on a boat, I guess the largest lift would be the [Strépy-Thieu boat lift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Str%C3%A9py-Thieu_boat_lift). Using it costs 5.50 one way on one of their [tourist boats](http://voiesdeau.hainaut.be/tourisme/voiesdeauhainaut/en/template/template.asp?page=strepy&navcont=5,0,0&branch=4).

Answer (score 10):

Fujitec [claims](http://www.fujitec.co.jp/english/project/transit.html) that its 120-passenger lifts at Dubai International Airport are “the world’s largest passenger capacity observation elevator model”. The [airport media gallery](http://www.dubaiairport.com/en/media-centre/Pages/ConcourseA.aspx) has some photos.

Goods lifts/freight elevators can be much larger than passenger lifts, though probably less accessible to the travelling public. For example, there are two at Barclays Center in Brooklyn that you can [drive a bus in to](http://bleacherreport.com/articles/1525276-kobe-nba-stars-ride-most-epic-elevator-in-sports).

Answer (score 6):

Normally it is measured in the number of passengers that an elevator can carry.

There is a [80 passenger elevator](http://www.smartplanet.com/blog/smart-takes/mitsubishi-installs-worlds-largest-elevator-in-japan-80-passengers-per-car/) installed in Japan.

Comment: he did specifically ask in terms of square footage tho (although I agree with your definition)

Comment: Technically you can consider the elevator on an aircraft carrier to be the largest since a human can ride on them.  http://blogs.howstuffworks.com/brainstuff/world-record-138-the-largest-people-elevators-in-the-world/

Comment: Yeah, I figure that most elevators aren't measured in sqft, but was curious.

Comment: @Karlson I am not sure if you can call an Aircraft carrier's elevator "commercial"...

Comment: @uncovery Potato - tomato considering that some aircraft carriers are now museums that is open to debate. :)

Answer (score 3):

[The 3 Gorges dam boat lift is now operational](http://news.cnhubei.com/xw/jj/201601/t3513977.shtml). It can lift ships up to 3,000 tons up by 113 meters.

Answer (score 1):

There are freight elevators capable of lifting army tanks.  One such was used during WWII in Kansas City.  It's still in operation.

Comment: This feels more like an anecdote than an actual answer. Can you give more detail and some kind of citation?